# Changing parser delimiter for a special element

Tags: xtext

Here is a simplified instance of the language I am struggling to define:

```
test : potato_good
test2 : carrot_not_that_good 

B_test = help
C_test = 13
B_test2 = me
C_test2 = 37
```

As you can notice, the first part of the instance are declarations of some elements.

The second part contains two kinds of references to those elements. We will call them B and C references, each having a different semantics.

My first try at defining such language was this:

```
Model : A* (B|C)* ;

A: name=ID ':' ID ;

B: 'B_'[A] '=' ID ;
C: 'C_'[A] '=' NUMBER;

Terminal ID:  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | 0..9 | '_')*   ;
Terminal NUMBER:  ( 0..9 )*     ;
```

The problem with this definition is that the editor will expect a space between the prefix `'B_'` or `'C_'` and the reference to an element `A`.

**How would you do so that the parser can recognize a string of the kind 'B_test' as a instance of the B rule and not as a terminal?**

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

this is a lexer problem. since the lexer runs before the parser and is stateless it always lexe an ID. maybe you can try to workaround this using a custom lexer (don't know if there is a way to workaround this in antlr)

as a workaround you could try the following but that is not general solution

```
Model : ase+=A* bcs+=(B|C)* ;

A: name=ID ':' value=ID ;

B: 'B_' ref=[A] '=' value=ID ;
C: 'C_' ref=[A] '=' value=NUMBER;

terminal ID:  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_') |
    (  ('B'|'C')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')   ) |
    (  ('A'| ('D'..'Z') | 'a'..'z')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' |'_')+   ) 
;
terminal NUMBER:  ( '0'..'9' )*     ;
```

Comment: I would prefer not to hack something with custom lexers as I read changes in the xtext file, once a custom lexer has been put in place are likely to be breaking changes.   ref :http://consoliii.blogspot.com/2013/04/xtext-is-incredibly-powerful-framework.html